# C# "using alias directives" across all namespace

Tags: c#

Here I have,

```
namespace MyLibrary {
    public class Card {
        public virtual bool Check(CZArray array, DyString pointer, DLibNumber findCount) {}
    }
}
```

where CZArray, DyString, DLibNumber are from three separate unrelated libraries. (Some different assemblies as well).

class "Card" is part of another library I'm building.

I'd like whoever using my library to be able to use my library without having to state "using CaseZero; using DynamicText; using DynamicValueLib; using MyLibrary;" every time they want to use derive the base Card class.

So they would only do

```
using MyLibrary;

public class SpecialCard : Card {
    public override bool Check(CZArray array, DyString pointer, DLibNumber findCount) {}
}
```

without having to use "using" or Namespace.ClassType.

I've been told using alias directives is limit to the file. Is there any way to use this?

I tried having a wrapper class of those variables by deriving them, but then it doesn't seem like there's a way to forward that call to the base class.

For example,

```
CZArrayDerivedInMyLibrary.czarrayFunction();
```

wouldn't be possible at all unless I create every function in the derived class.

Comment: As of C#7, the language hasn't addressed this issue. From that you can infer how much pain it really causes people to add the using directives -- not a whole lot.

Comment: _"I'd like whoever using my library to be able to use my library without having to state "using CaseZero; using DynamicText; using DynamicValueLib; using MyLibrary;" every time they want to use derive the base Card class."_ -- they already can do that. They just need to type `override`, then a space, and VS will show them a list of overridable methods. Once they pick `Check` from the list, the editor will insert a skeleton implementation, including having exactly the right types. If `using` directives are not present, fully-qualified type names will be used, which is perfectly legal and fine.

Comment: Also, a point of clarification: the `using` keyword is used in two different ways (well, now three, including static usings). The first is to bring a whole namespace into scope; this is the usage you seem to be asking about. The second is to alias a type name; you seem to incorrectly be using the word "alias" in your question, and it's confusing because of this dual usage.

Comment: @PeterDuniho it may be fine for you, but that's not what I asked. I guess it's not possible. I am using "alias" right. You just didn't understand the post well. The original question was if it's possible to use "using alias" across all namespace, not just tied to a file because my problem would have been solved if "using Simple = CaseZero.CArray;" could apply to all namespace.

Comment: @EdPlunkett That's a shame. I guess I'll keep force them to to use the namespace with the type name for now. The amount of complains I get from my team... it was just unbearable. Blame Microsoft X)

Comment: @user6516781 They're complaining to *you*? Man, I'd be sending out resumes if I had to work with people like that. Do they know about the refactoring context menu item that'll add a using for you?

Comment: @PeterDuniho Thanks for marking this question as "exact duplicate"...

Comment: @EdPlunkett They are not directed towards me, but more of a complaint. We have six programmers and they just were talking about this "inconvenience" way too often so I figured maybe I could help them.

Comment: @user6516781 Ah, OK -- it sounds better when you put it like that.